# Bounding Numbers for $N>2$

Tags: optimization, polygons, conjectures, plane-geometry

**Conjecture:**

"For any $N$ number of points placed arbitrarily in the plane, the minimum number of lines need to bound each point in a separate polygon(which we will call B), is equal to: 2+ ceiling($n/2$),regardless of the placement of the $N$ Points."

Restrictions:

1. $N$ is an integer greater than 2

2.All of the points together may not be co-linear
(Although subgroups of points may be co-linear)

3.You may only use straight lines

4.Lines drawn may not intersect your starting points

**The questions is, Can you prove or disprove the Conjecture above, and if it is false, What is the formula for finding B?**

Here's an Example using three points in an orderly arrangement:

[Example for $N=3$](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1az5kPIBRXfxvOnONhv0DEW34_lE0Lk-Ft7CLLTN9Bj8/edit?usp=sharing)

In the example, $N=3$ and $B=4$, as we were able to bound each of the individual three points into heir own separate polygon using the minimum number of lines:$4$

Example of what was said in comment, n=10,b=8, formula holds
[image]

Counter example to all co linear but one:

Comment: This doesn't look close to being true to me.  Suppose all the points are on the $x-$axis, at $x$ coordinates $1,2,3,4,...,n.$  Then you need $n-1$ lines just to separate them from each other, never mind enclosing them in polygons.  I know you said not all the points are collinear, but just add one non-collinear point.  Did you base your conjecture on more than one example?

Comment: I based the conjecture of the idea that first I can draw a triangle around any group of points. Then inside my triangle I can use lines to continue to divide the dots into groups of size n/2 , then n/4, then n/8, eventually ending up with 1 dot in each group. This leaves you with a bounding number of 3 from the triangle, plus n/2,: 3+(n/2). But this only works with an even number of points. but by using the ceiling function , we hallways just add on one more line to finish off the one pesky left over point that results when using this method for a odd value of N.

Comment: I will update to include an example of what I just explained above in this comment, and also a example to show why your point about have most of the dots be on the x-axis, doesn't imply needing n-1 lines.

Comment: Hmm... Interesting. Your example is puzzling. I will look it over but for now you have stumped me. I'm only 13 so it is hard for me to check very well, but at least I tried. In the mean time here is another puzzle: If you order the natural numbers in a grid, starting with 1 in the first box, go down a row, then 2 in the first bow, 3 in the second, go down a row, then 4,5,6, etc., then all the numbers on the rightmost diagonal will always be triangular numbers. Why? Ill post an example above

Comment: If you have a new question to ask, you should post it as a new question. It is inappropriate to edit an existing question to replace a previous question with a new one.

Comment: Ok sorry. I didn't know.